# Updating annotation's tag value without removing & readding annotations in mapview

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have a requirement where I need to update my all annotations tags after removing every annotation.

You may be asking why not you are using `removeAnnotations` & `addAnnotation`? 
The answer is, the no. of pins are really huge (~3000 for each polygon). So removing all annotations & readding those once again make a really annoying blink on the map. So I tried the following code:

```
-(void)deletePin
{
    [MyMapView deselectAnnotation:currentAnnotationView.annotation animated:NO];
    //currentAnnotationView is the selected annotationView

    [self.arrAreaPin removeObjectAtIndex:currentAnnotationView.tag];
    //arrAreaPin holds all pin's properties(tag, title, pin color, etc)

    [MyMapView removeAnnotation:currentAnnotationView.annotation];

    if (currentAnnotationView.tag<self.arrAreaPin.count)
    {
        NSUInteger index = 0;
        for (id<MKAnnotation>annotation in MyMapView.annotations)
        {

            if (![annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
            {
                MyMapAnnotation *myAnn = (MyMapAnnotation *)annotation; //MyMapAnnotation is the custom MKAnnotation with some added properties like locationType(I stored the array index in it)
                myAnn.locationType = index; //Updating with array index after deleting a pin

                MKAnnotationView *annView = [MyMapView viewForAnnotation: annotation];
                NSLog(@"Before updating Annotation tag: %lu",annView.tag);
                annView.tag = index;

                NSLog(@"After updating Annotation tag: %lu",(unsigned long)annView.tag);
            }
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

But it looks like the way the for loop picks the annotations from mapview doesn't match with the order of arrAreaPin array. So when I'm printing the tag value of annotationView before & after updating annonation tag it looks like :

```
Before updating Annotation tag: 0
After updating Annotation tag: 0

Before updating Annotation tag: 10
After updating Annotation tag: 1

Before updating Annotation tag: 16
After updating Annotation tag: 2

Before updating Annotation tag: 5
After updating Annotation tag: 3

Before updating Annotation tag: 17
After updating Annotation tag: 4
```

So basically its looks like the for loop is picking annotation randomly from map. Am I right?

Is it possible to update annotation's tag orderly? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for in` loop that you use processes the array elements in the order they are stored in the `MyMapView.annotations` array.
You said that you want them to be processed *„orderly“*. I assume that you want to process them in their `tag` order, which is obviously not the order the elements are stored in the array. So you had to sort them by `tag` order before you process them.
So my suggestion is to use something like (has been edited due to Poles comment below):

```
// Get your annotations (without the user location)
NSArray *myAnnotations = [MyMapView.annotations filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(MKAnnotation *annotation, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return ![annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]];
}]];

// Sort your annotations by their tag
NSArray *sortedAnnotations = [myAnnotations sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(MKAnnotation *a, MKAnnotation *b) {
    MKAnnotationView *annViewA = [MyMapView viewForAnnotation: a];
    MKAnnotationView *annViewB = [MyMapView viewForAnnotation: b];
    return [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:annViewA.tag] compare:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:annViewB.tag]];
}];

// Update the tags
for (id<MKAnnotation>annotation in sortedAnnotations) {
    MyMapAnnotation *myAnn = (MyMapAnnotation *)annotation;
    myAnn.locationType = index;
    MKAnnotationView *annView = [MyMapView viewForAnnotation: annotation];
    NSLog(@"Before updating Annotation tag: %lu",annView.tag);
    annView.tag = index;
    NSLog(@"After updating Annotation tag: %lu",(unsigned long)annView.tag);
    index++;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked I think. But a small changes needed. In `sortedArrayUsingComparator` we need to use `return [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:annViewA.tag] compare:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:annViewB.tag]];` instead of `[annViewA.tag compare:annViewB.tag]`.

Comment: @ Poles Thanks for your correction! I have edited my code above as you suggested.